# How to route to a page which has dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, css, drop-down-menu, routes

I have a website which has dropdowns and I want to route to the main page of the dropdown then I can navigate to that particular section of a page

Explanation: I have a page called Achievements and in that page, I have the dropdown which is sections when I click on the achievements it should redirect to that page and then using that dropdown menu I will move to that particular section

Below the code:

```
<li class="dropdown sm-scrn">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
             aria-expanded="true" data-hover="dropdown" href="https://www.innovkraft.com/">
                                    Achievements
       </a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href="">Awards & Recognition</a></li>
           <li><a href="">Academic Achievements</a></li>
           <li><a href="">Transport Service</a></li>
           <li><a href="">RCIS in media</a></li>
           <li><a href="">News & Events</a></li>
        </ul>
```

First I need to navigate to the main page then I can move to the particular section using the dropdown.

How to solve it?

Comment: You have to explain a little bit better your questions. However, you can achieve this by using anchor links.

Comment: Need to explain it more.. Right now it is not understandable.

Comment: I feel he meant that he wants to redirect to a particular section on a webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `id` of the section to navigate to a particular section.

```
<li class="dropdown sm-scrn">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true" data-hover="dropdown" href="https://www.innovkraft.com/achievements">
            Achievements
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href="https://www.innovkraft.com/achievements/#id-of-awards-section">Awards & Recognition</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://www.innovkraft.com/achievements/#id-of-academic-section">Academic Achievements</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://www.innovkraft.com/achievements/#id-of-transport-section">Transport Service</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://www.innovkraft.com/achievements/#id-of-RCIS-section">RCIS in media</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://www.innovkraft.com/achievements/#id-of-news-section">News & Events</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

If achievement is your page with URL `https://www.innovkraft.com/achievements` then it's related sections will have `id` which will help in navigating.

```
https://www.innovkraft.com/achievements/#id-of-awards-section
```

Make sure all the sections have `id` and should match the `id` in the dropdown link.

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Please check my modified answer.

Comment: your answer worked thank you but during the mobile responsive the toggle menu wont close when I am routing in a single page

Comment: can you go through this https://www.loom.com/share/fef30ec1a533479bbed5b8e37ad33873 video link